# I have a problem setting up git repository and pushing changes in visual studio code

Tags: git, gitlab

how to set git up in vs code. help i cant set it up. When i try to push a commit it shows cant find repository and shows a publish branch button and it opens a windows saying set core.fwmonitor to true. how to push a chnage to you git repository main branch

Answer (score 0):

First of all to being able to use Github with VSCode is to set-up Git on your computer and enable in it VSCode.

3. Enable Git in VS Code

1. Go to File > Preferences.
2. Go to Settings.
3. Type Git: Enabled in the search bar.
4. Make sure that the box is ticked.

**References :**

check the bellow reference example for mere steps

https://www.jcchouinard.com/install-git-in-vscode/

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not initilize git till now  in your project ,

simply run `git init` in your project folder

the message should say Reinitialized existing Git  or now initilized.

if not, then check weather you have git set it up properly or not.

now you can stage and then commit changes to your repo.

if you want to push code to remote branch then, you have to first set origin
where you want to push.

```
git remote add origin your_repo_url
```

**Hope it works.**